# How to read video card specifications?

Tags: video, uefi

I am trying to find out which video card is ready for UEFI. The problem is that I could not find any hint in the specification of the the video cards. No mention as "UEFI ready" or "GOP". Please do not recommend any software to check physically the video card, I know a lot of such software. My goal is to choose a NEW video card on the base of the specifications by the manufacturer. (I would not like to call dozens of dealers to clear it.)

Comment: Is there any reason you're expecting most of them _not_ to be UEFI-ready in 2021?

Comment: According to the dupe any card newer than an NVidia 7xx or an AMD 4xx, basically anything from 2013 onwards should fully support UEFI. Many older cards may still be fine as well but it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: Maybe the question is strange, but my friends really had problems with nvidia 7xx series. Some of them were installed and working normally, other not: no GOP or no UEFI ready. 
I have in my HP Z220 workstation an NVIDIA QUADRO 2000, which is impossible to use with secure boot enabled. I would not like to buy a very expensive new video card as I never use the PC for gaming. But the security is important for me, and it seems that for enabling secure boot I need a new card. The speed, the latency is not important for me. Just work and seeing movies...

Comment: I received this "This question already has an answer here:
How does one find GPUs that use UEFI GOP instead of legacy VBIOS? " But this is not true. My question was not the same. My question was about the specifications of the manufacturer. Or on an other way: Why the manufacturers specifications do not show this detail?